# Why does an async method perform a HTTP request only once here?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1, windows-store, dotnet-httpclient

In brief, here is a Windows Store application that fails to make more than one HTTP request when run with <kbd>F5</kbd> in Visual Studio 2013. The target platform is Windows 8.1.

Every time a button is clicked, it is supposed request time information from a public server and display the response. However, as Fiddler shows, an actual HTTP request is made only for the first click, despite the relevant click event handler being run over and over again.

I have gone through the [API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.getstringasync.aspx) and several other places, still nothing. Perhaps I am overlooking some kind of a configuration issue but I cannot imagine what it could be. Maybe someone here can?

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Web.Http;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace TestWindowsStore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private readonly Uri timeInfoHost = new Uri("http://jsontime-sharpnet.rhcloud.com/");
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
            headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("ie");
            headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeInfo ti = await PerformTimeRequest();
            this.TimeText.Text = ti.datetime;
        }

        private async Task<TimeInfo> PerformTimeRequest()
        {
            string json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(timeInfoHost);
            return Deserialize<TimeInfo>(json);
        }

        public T Deserialize<T>(string json)
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                var jser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T) jser.ReadObject(ms);
            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TimeInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string tz;
        [DataMember]
        public string hour;
        [DataMember]
        public string datetime;
        [DataMember]
        public string second;
        [DataMember]
        public string error;
        [DataMember]
        public string minute;
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Class="TestWindowsStore.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestWindowsStore"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox Name="TimeText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,242,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" Width="144"/>
    <Button Content="Get Time Async" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="648,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Why aren't any subsequent requests made? How can I fix it?

Comment: You are most likely reading a cached copy of the file at the given URL...

Comment: @ChrisK - Could be but **where** is the copy being cached? And how can I empty or disable that cache?

Comment: I think HttpClient will use the "global" IE cache. Can you try to append a random GUID at the end as a variable, to prevent caching? So that the url looks something like "http://jsontime-sharpnet.rhcloud.com/?discard=GUID"

Comment: If the server setup the caching headers properly you should never have to worry about this.  Why would you want to retrieve the same representation twice across the network?  When the max-age expires, the next request should automatically go across the network.  If you must ignore the server caching directives then send a no-cache.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - You do not understand. The goal of this question was to find out why an explicitly commanded request was not being performed. As caching is not mentioned in [the docs for HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx), I assumed there isn't any. Had I known `HttpClient` caches representations according to HTTP headers, this question would not exist.

Comment: @Saul HttpClient doesn't cache representations. But HTTP has a layered architecture and the WinINet proxy which sits in between your HttpClient and the origin server does cache representations.  HttpClient does make the request but it only is getting as far as the WinInet proxy, so you don't see it happen in fiddler.  This is extra confusing because the System.Net.HttpClient when run under WinRT doesn't send requests via WinINet proxy.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - No kidding about the confusion. I think the need to be aware of such intimate details in a sense defeats the abstraction `HttpClient` is supposed to provide. Having the cache control directive located inside a class called `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` is almost as bad. PS. While troubleshooting this issue I also happened to read a post from your blog ([HttpClient, it lives, and it is glorious.](http://www.bizcoder.com/httpclient-it-lives-and-it-is-glorious)). I remember being extra pissed off when I discovered the WinRT implementation does not accept a `HttpClientHandler`.

Comment: @Saul  I have no idea why they decided to copy everything from the .net version but then rename MessageHandlers into filters.  Also be aware the WinRT version doesn't close connections on dispose, like the .net one does.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - and the WinRT version closes connections on ... ?

Comment: @saul  It lets the underlying connection pool deal with that, same way that HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse does it I guess. There is probably some kind of inactivity timeout that will close pooled connnections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why a request is performed only once here is because by default, `HttpClient` uses a cache to store responses according to received `Cache-Control` headers (similar to [HTTPClient Caching in .Net](http://blog.technovert.com/2013/01/httpclient-caching/)). There are two ways to work around it.

The easiest solution is to use `HttpBaseProtocolFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior` property to handle cases when you want to skip the cache:

```
var httpFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
httpFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = 
    Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(httpFilter);
```

However, a solution I consider cleaner is to modify your server so it includes the appropriate headers that tell browsers do not cache the response, i.e.:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

E.g.:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache

...
```

The second solution has two advantages:

- A content you will not use again is not stored in the client machine.
- Other requests can benefit from the cache (when using the same instance of `HttpClient`).

Comment: If you don't have access to the server you can send the no-cache option as a request header.